# Word vs. Ms-word

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Does it even matter or bother anyone that [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) is used in the context of [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word)?

I figure that updating the excerpt is not going to solve the problem of people misusing it.

a bonus from gunr2171
Interesting that there is 140 questions with [both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word+word)

If it doesn't bother anyone then I assume we just leave it alone and this post is redundant but in any other case how are we going to solve this issue?

Comment: Interesting that there is 140 questions with [both tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word+word).

Comment: If a tag's being misused, it should be removed from the questions misusing it. Otherwise, it becomes useless and should just be burninated entirely.

Comment: @Wooble manually traversing through [2179 questions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) Even if we do clean it up, there will be more questions(people) misusing it in the future

Comment: Shouldn't one be a synonym for the other?

Comment: @3524344: no. Read the tag wiki for [word]. It's a completely different concept.

Comment: I wonder if [tag:word] should be burninated. It's a meta-tag, as far as I can tell. I can't imagine anyone following it. Perhaps once it's be banished, we could reintroduce it as a synonym of [tag:ms-word] to avoid the inevitable reintroduction.

Comment: What @Duncan said - I cannot think of any situation where a "word" tag with the meaning "smallest semantic unit in a sentence" is of any use in a SO context. If the question is about NLP, the appropriate NLP tags should suffice; from a programming perspective, it shouldn't matter if OP wants to analyze words, sentences, lexemes etc.

Comment: @l4mpi, I'd've thought on SO, "word" would mean [an instruction set size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)).

Comment: @Michael right, there's that meaning too, which just makes it more ambiguous. But I can't think of a legitimate use case for that meaning of the tag either... and even if there was one, I'd say a `word-size` tag instead of a plain `word` tag would probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Browsing through questions tagged with [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) there is at least one example where it's being used to mean "a processor instruction word":

- [Reading shorts in 32-bits architectures (for example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820576/)

The vast majority of the other uses are as a synonym for [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word):

- [Can range be used to get text from hyperlinked bookmark from a supplemental document in Word 2010 VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505751)
- [Running VBA code on Word documents that do not have Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157360)
- [VBA paste from Excel to Word ends sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066389)

A smaller set use it as a meta-tag for "something to do with written words":

- [Better way to modify middle character of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027152)
- [Algorithm to remove words in corpus with small occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941948)
- [Is there an algorithm to identify the most salient word from a given set of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928121)

Clearly the tag is ill-defined and poorly applied. It would be most *correct* to use it in the CPU sense, but I think that it will too-often be used as a synonym for [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) for that to be applicable.

**I thinks its best left as a synonym for** [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) **and the tag removed from all non-Word questions.**

A few might be applicable for the [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) tag. In most non-Word questions it's not adding value.