# Let’s have a [word] about this tag again

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

### Problem

The tag appears to be quite a mess. Its actual purpose is related to the unit "word" used in the context of [processors/computer architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)).

However, it is used as you would imagine for lexical issues and of course for issues related to [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word).
The issue had already been raised [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255005/word-vs-ms-word). That was in 2014. The tag is still (or again) being used incorrectly.

**Status:** As of writing, there are [2,362 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) with the compromised tag, many of which seem to be unrelated to processors.

Given the current state of constant, unresolvable missuses, the tag can not function with the intended purpose.

### Proposed Solution

- <s>[Reconsider burning the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407053/any-last-words). The main reason the burn has been declined was the fact that `word` in the processor context is a justified tag, which would be resolved by the new tag.</s> Rename the tag as suggested by [`@Zoe stands with Ukraine`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe-stands-with-ukraine)

Comment: Note that there was [a burnination request last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407053/any-last-words).

Comment: "The main reason the burn has been declined was the fact that word in the processor context is a justified tag, which would be resolved by the new tag" - that's a (possibly complex) _rename,_ not a burnination. It still doesn't meet the burnination criteria

Comment: Re *"word-unit"*: It isn't easy to find a tag name that is descriptive on its own, without (too much) extra context. *word-register-size*? *word-[cpu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit)-register-size*? (though less precise) *cpu-word*? *cpu-register-word*?

Comment: Some tags end up ambiguous just because the original term they were named after was badly named to begin with. This is such a case - to call a "double byte" or equivalent for _word_ was an incredibly stupid idea but that practice goes back to the 1950s if not earlier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Current steps:

1. Cleanup of incorrectly tagged question <s>(I can do only 5 suggest edits at a time, so help is appreciated.)</s> Anyone with 2k rep would be willing to do that?
2. Discussion for how to rename the [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) tag

Rename candidates gathered from this and the [related burninate-post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407053/any-last-words):

- word-unit
- word-frequency
- word-register-size
- word-cpu-register-size
- cpu-word
- cpu-register-word
- word-size
- word-memory-size
- memory-word
- word-computer-architecture
- machine-word
- <s>w´ô`rd</s>

3. Vote on rename candidates [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424224/14998487) (done)

Comment: "I can do only 5 suggest edits at a time, so help is appreciated" No, please refrain from doing that. Users with less than 2k rep shouldn't participate in tag clean ups/re-tagging, since they create immense amounts of edit review work otherwise.

Comment: How is w´ô`rd a rename canidate?

Comment: @Daedalus just a joke entry. A bit of fun in an otherwise dull thread.

Comment: If we have additional candidate replacement tag terms to add to this list, should we add them in a comment or should we edit this answer?

Comment: Doesn't the cleanup bump the questions to the top of the current list, and if so, is that a problem?

Comment: @shoover 1. Just edit the answer to add candidates. 2. I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: @A-Tech I think shoover was referring to bumping the questions tagged with the `word` tag not this question itself

Comment: I edited a few yesterday. I also flagged for closure one that was only about [tag:ms-word] but not about programming in [tag:ms-word], per the tag and stack description.