# We need a better [word] for this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) tag has clear guidance on its usage.  It's about a size of data in memory.  Despite this, it is [constantly confused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255005/208273) with [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word).  The most recent 21 questions in [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) are actually about Microsoft Word, the next one is about words in a string, followed by 12 more about Microsoft Word, followed by one that...okay, I have no idea why [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75715187/208273) is tagged with [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word).  At that point I stopped looking.  None of the recent questions with this tag are using it correctly.

We're [not going to remove it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407053/208273), and we've decided that [the best solution is to rename it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421365/208273), but...to what?  We've discussed ideas but never really sat down and picked one.

**What would be a good name for this tag about "the amount of data that a processor can fit in its general-purpose registers"?**  It should 1) clearly convey the intended meaning, but more importantly 2) not be confusable with Microsoft Word (or words in a string, but that's not most of the misuse).

Ideas for inspiration include these from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421365/208273) by A-Tech:

> - word-unit
> - word-frequency
> - word-register-size
> - word-cpu-register-size
> - cpu-word
> - cpu-register-word
> - word-size
> - word-memory-size
> - memory-word
> - word-computer-architecture
> - machine-word

Please post suggestions with reasoning, one per answer (so that they can be voted on more easily).

Comment: I think my favorite rename candidates are (in order) [memory-word] and [cpu-word], though I don't have super strong feelings or especially fleshed-out reasoning just yet.

Comment: I still don't really see the need for this tag. Shouldn't tagging the question with [cpu-registers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cpu-registers/info) / [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/memory/info) / the specific word-size (e.g. byte) be enough? Who is a SME in only cpu words, that is also not a SME in registers / memory / the specific (hopefully tagged) cpu architecture? I invite to disagree.

Comment: word-size is maybe a better name.

Comment: @Lino I admit that I'm _also_ skeptical of this tag, but removing it has been [previously rejected by the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407053/208273).  At the very least, I think we can all agree that we need to stem the bleeding of misuse.  Once the inflow of incorrect questions is stopped and the existing mess is cleaned up, it might be possible to assess the correctly tagged questions and see if there's a good solution to improve the situation there as well. Right now there's way too much noise from the misuse for anyone to really understand the correct usage.

Comment: I don't think that bad [word]s should be allowed in questions.

Comment: [tag:data-word]

Comment: Many of the questions using this tag are using it in the sense of a word in English. Example: a question about splitting a sentence into words is tagged with [word]. What should be done with those? Remove the [word] tag? Is there a better tag for this?

Comment: Could there be a better tag? [word].

Comment: @Lino: Agreed, I don't think we need a tag for it.  It's simply part of [computer-architecture] (which is a tag-synonym of [cpu-architecture].)  With modern architectures typically having wider busses and SIMD registers than their ancestors, word-size has become less and less relevant of a concept, especially when x86 was the only important architecture for a lot of programmers.  (No longer the case anymore.)  [x86 is very much not word-oriented for data or instructions.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32548409/224132) and [this re: instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68229585/224132).

Comment: When I've tagged [word] on a question, I've only done so because it applied and there weren't 5 other tags that applied more.  Not because I ever really expected anyone to filter a search by that tag.  Although to be fair it did help me find my x86 answer I wanted to link just now.  Other ISAs do care more about certain size chunks, but it's often not exactly what they call a word, or the register width.  e.g. store-buffer coalescing block sizes in [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217528)

Comment: @NickODell [tag:lexical-word]?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In terms of the order of what I think is least likely to be misintepreted by people who don't have much technical background in the hardware side of things, I think [cpu-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpu-word) is good.

I think fewer people will know what "machine" in [machine-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-word) is specifically referring to here, and my gut thinks that even fewer people will know what "memory" in [memory-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-word) is referring to. Or maybe I have the order of those two flipped.

General reasoning: CPU doesn't have a lot of various meanings, while I'd expect that "machine" and "memory" can refer to more things in various contexts. Ex. imagine somebody trying to make a game where you memorize words, or just writing a program that does things with words that runs on a machine.

Is the [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) tag supposed to be for questions about machine word size? If so, then yes, I think the tag name should have the word "size" in it. If not, then I think it shouldn't.

Comment: As the only SO user with a gold badge in [cpu-architecture], I think this sounds reasonable.  Thanks for your perspective that [machine-word] might not be immediately obvious as a name for the concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture) - that's the name I tend to use when talking about word-oriented architectures like MIPS where that concept is even meaningful (where many different things use the same size, like instructions, registers, cache access, perhaps even the external data bus).

Comment: As someone fairly new to the field I fully agree with your [tag:cpu-word] vote.

Comment: This has now been done; thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 17):

Combining the suggestions for [word-size](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424224/we-need-a-better-word-for-this-tag#424226) and [cpu-word](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424224/we-need-a-better-word-for-this-tag#424227), how about

[cpu-word-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpu-word-size)

It's descriptive: the tag is for questions relating to the CPU's word size.  It includes the word "size" to clarify that it's about a size.  And there's no possible way (famous last words) to confuse it with Microsoft Word or anything about string processing.

Comment: Maybe with synonyms from [word-size] and [cpu-word] as well, just to make it easier to find.

Comment: is the tag supposed to be for questions strictly about word size? I haven't looked at the past questions, have not participated in the tag ever, and have only seen the tag guidance and wiki, which don't seem to state that the questions have to be about size. Granted, I can't really think of what else one would ask about off the top of my head.

Comment: @user broadly, yes, assuming you include things like processing data one word at a time as "about word size".  That may not be entirely clear from the name, though.  It is difficult to find example questions due to the _vast majority_ of the tag's usage being incorrect.

Comment: I don't love [cpu-word-size] as a tag name.  Some questions related to the concept could be about how to write a C program (or whatever other language) that processes a string one machine word at time (instead of one byte at a time), e.g. an `strlen` implementation using https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord

Comment: An SO question about that could be what C type to pick that tends to be as large as a single register but not larger, so you can do bithacks efficiently.  Not what the word size of different CPUs is.  Or just how to implement an SWAR algorithm that handles multiple bytes at once, not caring too much exactly what size a word is.  The word "size" in the tag name seems awkward in that case, like it's tied to questions about what the size is, not about how to use whole words, or how CPUs process them.

Answer (score 6):

Rename to "word-size".

Additionally synonymize *a new* "word" tag with "ms-word" (as it seems to be the most common case next to usage as shortcut for "word-boundary").

Comment: My only worry about this otherwise good suggestion is that it could be confused with string length (or...I dunno, something related to the size of things in MS Word?).  I'm not sure how likely that is.

Comment: This will be confused with word-lengths in texts. E.g. a very basic algorithm for recognizing the language of a longer text could compare the average length of a word (or sloppy: `word-size`). If you're just comparing German and English, such an algorithm might even be used in production because of its speed. String manipulation is also a classic class of beginner exercises, adding another risk there.

Comment: In fact, on one of the earlier Q&As about this tag, it was found that hundreds of questions in it are about words in text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407056/4691830

Answer (score 4):

I like `[data-word]`, or maybe `[binary-word]` or `[word-data-size]`.  This emphasizes that this is a unit of binary data, which ultimately is what it boils down to.  I also have no real qualms with the suggestion of `[word-computer-architecture]`.

### Other suggestions in the question

I haven't had to deal with computer architecture at this level in a long time, and never professionally, so take my suggestions and understanding with that in mind.  But even so, the other suggestions seem to be lacking in some ways.

The CPU suggestions (`[cpu-word]`, `[word-cpu-register-size]`) feel a little… overly specific to me, at least at a glance.  Couldn't any processor deal with data in words, and not just the central processor?

The `[word-memory-size]` and `[memory-word]` suggestions are… fine, but can't words also refer to data on disk, and not just in memory (even if they are more typically used when describing memory and program register data)?

`[word-size]` or `[word-unit]` are OK, but it feels like `[word-data-size]`/`[word-data-unit]` better emphasize that this is a size of data, and not, e.g. the size of an English or other language word or something.

`[word-frequency]` feels completely wrong.  It's not a unit of frequency, plus this term makes my brain jump to thinking of the frequency of a given English or other language word in a piece of text.

I don't think `[machine-word]` really works.  That doesn't feel like standard terminology, and therefore it has me asking: "what type of machine"?

Comment: [data-word] seems pretty terrible.  It's not idiomatic and sounds awkward.  Moreover, on word-oriented machines like MIPS, instructions are usually a machine word as well.  I thought "machine word" was standard terminology; I've used it plenty of times to mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture).  (Not that I recommend [word-computer-architecture], though: it's too long, and risks confusion as being about ISAs that have word-addressable memory.  Not that "word architecture" is a standard term.)

Comment: Memory can also refer to disk and tape, although the narrower interpretation is often used.

Comment: *therefore it has me asking: "what type of machine"* - The specific machine (CPU) you're talking about, of course.  A "word" isn't a standard size across all architectures, so it only makes sense in the context of a specific target.  Or in a higher-level language like C, a size that is hopefully appropriate for the target, e.g. `unsigned long int` or maybe `uintptr_t`.  (But different choices by different implementations mean there isn't any standard type you can use that's reliably the max width of an integer register or a load/store.)

Answer (score 1):

As we are dealing with a *unit* of measurement (as per [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/word/info)), I belive that [word-unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-unit) would be most appropiate.

Answer (score -2):

```
computing-unit-word
```

derived from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)).

> In computing, a word is the natural unit of data used by a particular processor design.

Comment: Honestly - if I read "computing-unit-word" I'd still need to read the tag wiki to understand *what that even is*. I don't think it's a useful short descriptor. My first guess would be that it's a unit for computing text length.

Answer (score -8):

I feel uncomfortable with the use of 'word' in any combination with other specifiers, as the meaning of word itself controversion - is it 16-bits (most programming languages) or do we interpret it as a literary unit (which isn't really appropiate here?

Ahem, sorry for this, but I thought let's consult AI. Chat-GPT answered `register-capacity` for the question **"the amount of data that a processor can fit in its general-purpose registers".**

I rather like `register-capacity`.

Comment: I fear absolutely no one will know what that's supposed to mean or find it. Is it the number of registers on the cpu? Number of registers that can be addressed by an instruction?

Comment: [tag:register-size] actually doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact: The tag about the increasingly-nebulous term "word" needs to include the word "word".  It's not always the same thing as register width.  e.g. MIPS64 still uses "word" to mean 32-bit chunks, and instructions that operate on full registers are double-word operations like `dadd $t0, $t1, $t2`.

Comment: (But if you're talking about a "word-at-a-time" implementation of `strlen` or something, you would normally mean a full register of data.  That's why the term "word" is only useful when you don't need to be specific, or can rely on your audience to know what you mean, or are using it as a technical term with a specific meaning in the context of one ISA, such as x86 where it's 16-bit, MIPS where it's 32-bit, etc..)  Anyway, the tag has now been renamed to [cpu-word], which is a good choice.